# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setValid' . How to remove this warning

Tags: reactjs

Im new to react and have been using useEffect for the first time. Im getting warning of missing dependecy, but the app works perfectly. How can I solve the warning? Or is it okay to ignore this warning?

```
useEffect(() => {
   setValid(true);
}, []};
```

Im getting the warning : React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setValid'.

Comment: Add setValid to the dependecy array

Comment: Why do you use a hook to initialize `setValid` on first render? Why not use the initializer syntax for `useState`?

Answer (score 2):

easy  just pass `setValid` as the dependency

```
   setValid(true);
}, [setValid]};
```

Answer (score 0):

As  NeERAJ TK mentioned, React linter is complaining about not having setValid in the array of dependencies:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setValid(true);
}, [setValid]};
```

I assume that `setValid` is a setter generated by the use hook inside your component. If you will pass a function in the array of dependencies and will just call a `setState` inside your `useEffect`, you will run into an infinite loop so you will have to memoize or find a different approach.

In this case, I would suggest not using `useEffect` in general, and pass a default value to `setState`:

```
const [valid, setValid] = useEffect(true);
```